# Generating Beta-Binomial responses with covariates

Tags: r

I am trying to generate Beta-Binomial data with regressors using R. I have used the following code to generate Beta-Binomial data. Now I want to add a covariate to the equation. Appreciate any help.

```
set.seed(111) 
k<-20
n<-60
x<-NULL

p<-rbeta(k,3,3)# so that the mean nausea rate is alpha/(alpha+beta)
for(i in 1:k)
x<-cbind(x,rbinom(300,n,p[i]))
```

Thanks
Anamika

Comment: How is this regression? It is generation of data from a model.

Comment: Thanks David. This is a generation of Beta-Binomial data. I am also looking to generate the covariate data (or treatment data) using the same model but with regressors, which my code doesnot include.

Comment: My earlier comment was incorrect; I should have said that `x` could be generated as `t(sapply(p, function(p.i) rbinom(300, n, p.i)))`

Answer (score 4):

My *guess* is that you want to generate data from a model where the probability of the outcome (nausea in your case) is a function of covariates.  The most standard (although not the only) way to do this is to parameterize the underlying Beta distribution in terms of its mean `(alpha/(alpha+beta))` and a shape, or overdispersion, parameter that determines the variance (typically equivalent to `alpha+beta`; larger theta means *smaller* variance).  Furthermore, it is probably easiest to make the mean a logistic function of the covariate (you could substitute a different inverse-link function if you wanted).

The `rbetabinom` function in the `emdbook` package is already parameterized in this way (you can look at the code -- it's not very complicated).

```
set.seed(111)
beta0 <- 0 ## logit rate at x=0
beta1 <- 2 ## increase in logit-prob(nausea) per unit x
k <- 20
n <- 60
theta <- 6  ## shape parameter, equivalent to alpha+beta
x <- runif(k)  ## distribution of covariates 
               ## (you might want something different)

library(emdbook)
eta <- beta0+beta1*x  ## linear predictor
prob <- plogis(eta)   ## logistic transform
y <- rbetabinom(k, prob=prob, size=n, theta=6)
```

If you set `beta1` to zero you *should* get the same results as before (logistic(0)=0.5, the same as your mean), but I haven't actually checked.

**edit**: to get 300 replicates of this dataset,

```
Y <- replicate(300,rbetabinom(k, prob=prob, size=n, theta=6))
```

seems to work (gives a 20 x 300 matrix).  So does substituting `plyr::raply` for `replicate` and transposing (`r*ply` gives a little bit more consistency and control than `replicate`).

Comment: Thanks Ben, this was helpful. I was wanting to generate 300 simulated datatsets from the betabinomial above and I modified the last line of your code to for(i in 1:300) y<-cbind(y,rbetabinom(k,prob=prob,size=n,theta=6)) but I am getting warnings.

Comment: What warnings? Also, it might be a bit easier to do `replicate(300, rbetabinom(k,prob=prob,size=n,theta=6))`